# Unity memory issue Resources image

Tags: c#, memory, unity-game-engine, memory-leaks

I'm loading resources into unity but I don't know how to release them from memory.

I have a script that loads preview images like this:

```
//load the 12 images
        while (currentPreviewNumber < 12) {
            Debug.Log (currentPreviewNumber);
            byte[] tBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes (Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + currentPreviewNumber + ".jpg");
            Texture2D texture = new Texture2D (100, 100);
            texture.LoadImage (tBytes);

            sprites [currentPreviewNumber] = Sprite.Create (texture, new Rect (0, 0, mCamera.width, mCamera.height),
                new Vector2 (0.5f, 0.5f),
                40);

            currentPreviewNumber++;
        }
```

but everytime I run the code my memory usage doubles.  how do I release the sprites from memory when executing a second time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Some would say `GC.Collect()` but this is not the case here. Your code can be optimized to reduce memory allocation.

**1**. What's causing most of these memory allocation is `Sprite.Create`. It allocates memory so bad. The solution is to change your design. Use `RawImage` array instead of `Sprite` array and this unnecessary memory allocation would go away.

**2**.`Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(100, 100);` allocates memory too. Since it is always **100** by **100**, you can re-use it. Make it global and call new `new Texture2D(100, 100);` once, in the start. This saves memory allocation.

**3**.Use `StringBuilder` to concatenate `Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + currentPreviewNumber + ".jpg"`

**4**.`Application.persistentDataPath` allocates memory. Store it in a temporary value in the `Start()` function instead of calling it repeatedly in the while loop.

**Solution 1**:

```
public RawImage defaultRawImage;
RawImage[] rawImages;
Texture2D texture = null;
int currentPreviewNumber = 0;
string appPath;
System.Text.StringBuilder imagePath;

void Start()
{
    appPath = Application.persistentDataPath;

    //Init Texture 2D
    texture = new Texture2D(100, 100, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);

    //Init All 12 Raw Images
    rawImages = new RawImage[12];
    for (int i = 0; i < rawImages.Length; i++)
    {
        rawImages[i] = Instantiate(defaultRawImage) as RawImage;
    }

    //Init String Builder
    imagePath = new System.Text.StringBuilder(300);
}

void loadPreviewOptimized()
{
    while (currentPreviewNumber < 12)
    {
        //Debug.Log(currentPreviewNumber);
        imagePath.Capacity = 0;
        imagePath.Append(appPath).Append("/").Append(currentPreviewNumber).Append(".jpg");

        //Read File
        byte[] tBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath.ToString());
        texture.LoadImage(tBytes);

        rawImages[currentPreviewNumber].texture = texture;
        currentPreviewNumber++;
    }
}
```

The `byte[] tBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath.ToString());` code allocates memory to return bytes. To get rid of it, make `tBytes` a global variable then allocate memory only once. Below is a fully complete code when you want to stop the memory allocation with  File.`ReadAllBytes`.

**Solution 2**:

```
public RawImage defaultRawImage;
RawImage[] rawImages;
Texture2D texture = null;
int currentPreviewNumber = 0;
string appPath;
System.Text.StringBuilder imagePath;
byte[] tBytes;

void Start()
{
    appPath = Application.persistentDataPath;

    //Init Texture 2D
    texture = new Texture2D(100, 100, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);

    //Init All 12 Raw Images
    rawImages = new RawImage[12];
    for (int i = 0; i < rawImages.Length; i++)
    {
        rawImages[i] = Instantiate(defaultRawImage) as RawImage;
    }

    //Init String Builder
    imagePath = new System.Text.StringBuilder(300);
    tBytes = new byte[90000];
}


void loadPreviewOptimized()
{
    while (currentPreviewNumber < 12)
    {
        //Debug.Log(currentPreviewNumber);

        //Reset Capacity before Reading
        imagePath.Capacity = 0;
        imagePath.Append(appPath).Append("/").Append(currentPreviewNumber).Append(".jpg");

        //Read File
        using (System.IO.FileStream myfile = System.IO.File.Open(imagePath.ToString(), System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            //Check if array size is enough before writing
            if (tBytes.Length >= myfile.Length)
            {
                //OK (Write file to tBytes array)
                myfile.Read(tBytes, 0, (int)myfile.Length);
                texture.LoadImage(tBytes);
            }
            else
            {
                //NOT OK (Resize array size)
                tBytes = new byte[myfile.Length];

                //Write file to tBytes array
                myfile.Read(tBytes, 0, (int)myfile.Length);
                texture.LoadImage(tBytes);
            }

            rawImages[currentPreviewNumber].texture = texture;
            currentPreviewNumber++;
        }
    }
}
```

The memory it allocates now is 10.0kb which is fine. If you want to optimize this more, instead of generating a string with `StringBuilder` in the while loop, do it once in the `Start` function and store those string paths to string array that can be re-used with index later on in the while loop but the current code is fine.